# Not able to install Python Packages

Tags: python

I am using Python34 on 32 bit Windows 7. When I try to run "pip install pygame" on my cmd I run into the following error

C:\Users\Admin>pip install pygame
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

When I do echo PATH, this is the path that is set

C:\Users\Admin>echo %PATH%
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\Wind
owsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\W
indows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Python34\Scripts

How should I fix this?

Comment: You should [install pip](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4750806/119527).

Comment: pip is installed. I used the following to install pip C:\Python34\Scripts\pip3.exe and it was installed. Still I face the same error

Answer (score 0):

As he said pip is usually in C:\Python34\Scripts so its probably not installed. I would probably add C:\Python34\ to your path for python itself too while you are at it but even with pip installed you will probably get an error installing pygame that says "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)"  because it needs to compile it.

You can get Visual C++ 2010 Express for free at https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-2010-express

An alternitive method instead of having pip compile it is to get the binary wheel file you need from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

You can install it as a binary without the MS C/C++ compiler by using "pip install pygame.whl"

Comment: pip is installed. I used the following to install pip C:\Python34\Scripts\pip3.exe and it was installed. Still I face the same error

Comment: In your example it would be looking for pip.exe in that folder rather than pip3.exe. if you don't have a pip.exe you could probably just rename the file.

Comment: The Scripts file contain pip3 & pip3.4, there is no file named pip, will try running pip3.4. Thanks for your help

Comment: Even after installing pip3.4, still getting that error

Answer (score -1):

You can download it here [MS Visual C++ 10.0](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/D/9/1D9A6C0E-FC89-43EE-9658-B9F0E3A76983/vc_web.exe). And it will be work.
But i advice you, install Anaconda with Python 2.7 or 3.5 there is many easy installabe librares.